SwiftUI multi-line TextField inside ScrollView scrolls to bottom when focused
I have the following SwiftUI view:
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Aut voluptatibus sunt qui similique nulla quo neque omnis aut maxime labore. Et aspernatur vitae et maxime maiores eos galisum libero. Et necessitatibus nisi ut consequatur quisquam qui nulla voluptatem et exercitationem quam et neque eaque ad consequatur esse.

Vel aspernatur enim eum expedita vero sit rerum cupiditate et obcaecati sequi aut corrupti quam. Ut ullam veritatis qui tempore sunt eum voluptatibus voluptas At voluptas modi quo nulla nesciunt. Et eius maxime qui consequatur enim et fugiat vero et labore architecto eos nihil optio?

Id eveniet autem qui necessitatibus dolorem aut iusto optio eum dolorem dolore. Rem numquam architecto sit velit repellat rem ratione explicabo ut maxime omnis vel similique provident. Et sunt illo non porro aliquam ut fugiat atque At consequatur exercitationem ut autem officia qui rerum vero.

Non adipisci illum sed veritatis sint quo iste alias sit eaque autem qui voluptatem aperiam. Et dolores neque qui voluptas architecto qui fuga veritatis vel dolor vero. Ab voluptatibus laudantium qui accusamus eaque et galisum maxime et architecto error qui dolore tenetur aut maiores cupiditate qui tempore praesentium.

Quo molestias quos et itaque rerum qui perspiciatis corrupti cum quas quis. Eos voluptatibus omnis est rerum repudiandae ut autem eaque.

Ex quidem libero sed sint eligendi ea minus provident est sequi nemo qui consectetur facilis est quisquam autem et voluptate similique. Id odio placeat non laboriosam consequatur non saepe vitae ad excepturi dolore eos dolorum facilis hic corrupti obcaecati vel quod cumque. Vel ratione esse At maiores accusantium 33 vitae voluptas eos recusandae quidem ut aliquam voluptates ea quidem incidunt qui libero explicabo! Sed ullam repellendus in atque perspiciatis sed ratione exercitationem ut molestias consectetur sed voluptatibus voluptatem.

Ea pariatur earum vel unde natus non dolor magnam sit galisum amet qui impedit molestiae? Aut dolor repudiandae ut dignissimos tempora qui quam ipsam nam illo voluptas quo architecto iste et accusamus numquam. A fugiat fugit et dolorem saepe et saepe voluptas.

"""

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TextField("", text: self.$text, axis: .vertical)
        }
    }
}

When I tap on text at the top of the text view, the parent scrollview scrolls all the way to the bottom, preventing me from being able to see the text I am currently editing. This only happens when the view is not focused and becomes focused. If the keyboard is already there then this doesn't happen.
If I remove the parent ScrollView this issue does not exist. Is there a way to disable this functionality in SwiftUI?

If you add a .border(.red) to your textfield, you'll notice its height is bigger than the screen size. When the keyboard appears, it pushes the (entire) view up to make room for the keyboard by an amount equivalent to the size/height of the keyboard (about 300 pixels I think) - and it does so from the bottom of the view (which we saw is somewhere below the bottom edge of the screen). Note that the keyboard does not know where inside the textfield you placed the cursor.
You can fix this in two steps.
First, set a fixed or a max height for your textfield, so it does not go below the bottom edge of the screen:
TextField("", text: self.$text, axis: .vertical)
    .frame(maxHeight: 800) //arbitrary value as example

Second, force the ScrollView to ignore the area that would otherwise be occupied by the keyboard:
ScrollView {
    TextField("", text: self.$text, axis: .vertical)
        .frame(maxHeight: 800)
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)

Now you can set whatever height you want for the textfield based on your needs, but assuming you want it to take the entire height of the screen, you will need to account for various screen sizes - instead of hard coding a specific value.
To do so, you can use a GeometryReader to get the height of the container - in this case, the ScrollView which takes up the entire screen (add a red border to ScrollView also, if you want to verify that).
Here's what your struct's body will then look like:
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { container in // <-- Here, add a GeometryReader to get the size of the container
        ScrollView {
            TextField("", text: self.$text, axis: .vertical)
                .frame(maxHeight: container.size.height, alignment: .top) // <-- Here, set a height for the textfield, so it is not bigger than the screen height.
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) // <-- Here, prevent the keyboard from pushing the view up
    .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively) //optional - for convenience
    .padding() //optional - for some breathing room
}

